# The purpose of www-data user in apache2

Tags: configuration, permissions, apache2

So I have been wondering what the true purpose of www-data user/group is. Should I include other programmers into this group that will be editing the files in the website root? Should all of the documents be owned by www-data?

Answer (score 1):

1. "httpd" runs on ports 80 & 443, which basically means that it will be started as "root" and later dropped to "www-data".
2. Not really, the directory & files can be owned by another group "programmers" and "www-data" needs read-access only (via "others" group having read access)
3. "www-data" should not have write access unless it's necessary (like uploads directory, etc.), all it takes is "read" access for apache to be able to serve the page.